# Entity framework with Mysql "model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata"

Tags: mysql, asp.net, entity-framework

Net Asp MVC 5 Web Project it's running ok when using sql server local db. but i want to migrate to mysql database, i know one of main advantages of Entity framework is could use Any DBMS that contains a connector.

i've followed these tutorials for creating a web project with mySql database but with no results:

[ASP.NET: Setup a MVC5 website with MySQL, Entity Framework 6 Code-First and VS2013](http://www.ryadel.com/2014/10/20/asp-net-setup-mvc5-website-mysql-entity-framework-6-code-first-vs2013/)

[How to set up application using ASP.NET Identity with MySQL Provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w)

[ASP.NET Identity: Using MySQL Storage with an EntityFramework MySQL Provider](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/aspnet-identity-using-mysql-storage-with-an-entityframework-mysql-provider)

when running my project i got this message:
model compatibility cannot be checked because the database does not contain model metadata...

I'm using following version of theses tools
- Visual Studio 2013 update 4 
- Entity framework tools for visual studio 6.1.3
- Entity framework 6.1.3
- MySQl.Data.Entity 6.9.6
- MySql.Data 6.9.6

some parts of my web.config

Connection string:

```
  <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Server=localhost;Database=database;Uid=root;Pwd=root;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
```

Entity framework:

```
  <entityFramework>
<contexts>
  <context type="Tesis.DAL.ApplicationDbContext, Tesis">
    <databaseInitializer type="Tesis.DAL.ApplicationInitializer, Tesis" />
  </context>
</contexts>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlConnectionFactory, EntityFramework" />
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
<provider invariantName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlProviderServices, MySql.Data.Entity.EF6, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d">
  </provider></providers>
```

Db provider factories

```
    <DbProviderFactories>
  <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
  <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.9.6.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
</DbProviderFactories>
```

My ApplicationDbContext class:

```
 public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<User>
{
    public ApplicationDbContext(): base("DefaultConnection", throwIfV1Schema: false)
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new MySqlInitializer());
    }

    public static ApplicationDbContext Create()
    {
        return new ApplicationDbContext();
    }

    public virtual DbSet<CaseStudy> CaseStudies { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<InitialCharge> InitialCharges { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Section> Sections { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Semester> Semesters { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Evaluation> Evaluations { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<Question> Questions { get; set; }

    public virtual DbSet<QuestionOption> QuestionOptions { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<User>().ToTable("Users");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Roles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRoles");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaims");
        modelBuilder.Entity<Semester>().HasMany(x => x.Sections).WithOptional().HasForeignKey(e => e.SemesterId).WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

i've created MysqlInitializer class and MySqlHistoryContext class

MySqlInitializer class:

```
public class MySqlInitializer : IDatabaseInitializer<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public void InitializeDatabase(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Database.Exists())
        {
            // if database did not exist before - create it
            context.Database.Create();
        }
        else
        {
            // query to check if MigrationHistory table is present in the database
            var migrationHistoryTableExists = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<int>(
            string.Format(
              "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_schema = '{0}' AND table_name = '__MigrationHistory'",
              "teachlogistics"));

            // if MigrationHistory table is not there (which is the case first time we run) - create it
            if (migrationHistoryTableExists.FirstOrDefault() == 0)
            {
                context.Database.Delete();
                context.Database.Create();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Configuration class

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<ApplicationDbContext>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        ContextKey = "Tesis.DAL.ApplicationDbContext";
        // register mysql code generator
        SetSqlGenerator("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", new MySql.Data.Entity.MySqlMigrationSqlGenerator());
        SetHistoryContextFactory("MySql.Data.MySqlClient", (conn, schema) => new MySqlHistoryContext(conn, schema));
    }

    protected override void Seed(ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        UserBL.CreateFirstUser(context);
    }
}
```

MySqlHistoryContext class:

```
 public class MySqlHistoryContext : HistoryContext
{
    public MySqlHistoryContext(DbConnection connection, string defaultSchema)
        : base(connection, defaultSchema)
    {

    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.MigrationId).HasMaxLength(100).IsRequired();
        modelBuilder.Entity<HistoryRow>().Property(h => h.ContextKey).HasMaxLength(200).IsRequired();
    }
}
```

I don't know what im doing wrong, i have read several questions answered here and followed the tuts specially this: [How to set up application using ASP.NET Identity with MySQL Provider](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/788357/How-to-set-up-application-using-ASP-NET-Identity-w)

i would apreciate your help :)

thanks.

Comment: how are you creating the tables in your MySQL instance?

Comment: I'm Using code first, i think EF create them automatically when OnModelCreating runs...

Comment: and you created a custom `IDatabaseInitializer` for MySQL like all the tutorials mention, since MySQL doesn't support migrations out of the box?  and fixed the issues with the `__migrationHistory` table for MySQL?

Comment: Yes i did it, i updated my post if i missed something.

Comment: Oh! it works now!, but i dont know what i did different, anyway, tahnks for your great help :)

Comment: Ok I know the trick. I write my experience if anyone got this issue too. Before running my Web app I've just created my database called "database" (without tables) . There was the problem. you have to let entity framework creates even the database for you